# For Each - Inverted Order

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Object>`. I want to iterate over this list, but I want the order to be inverted, so when I use the object, it will start from the last to the first. How can I do it, minimal code?

Thanks.

**P.S.** I'm using C#, WinForms.

Answer (score 5):

Use the extension method [`Enumerable<T>.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will iterate through the list in a reverse order and leave the original list intact.

```
foreach(var item in list.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
{

}
```

`Reverse` , however, traverses the list and caches your items in a reverse order when iteration starts. In 90% of the cases this is fine, because it's still a O(n) operation, but if you want to avoid this cache just use a plain old `for`

```
for(int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) { }
```

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'void' because 'void' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: Also, how can I make sure the list stays the same after reverse is done?

Comment: @user3647752 Try with the updated code. I forgot `List<T>` defines its own `void Reverse` method.

Comment: There is no such thing "AsEnumerable" for List.

Comment: @user3647752 There is, it's an extension method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). Try importing `System.Linq`

Comment: Because I'm using AsEnmuerable, it won't reverse the original list's order, but the current one I'm using, right?

Comment: One minor thing: the for loop will generate a runtime error.

Comment: @user3647752 see above comment, the loop started from a non existent item.

Comment: @user3647752 `Enumerable.Reverse` creates a reversed *view* of the list. The list itself remains unchanged. In fact, all LINQ extension methods are pure functions, which means they have no observable side-effects.